# integrating protractor with Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, protractor, jenkins-plugins

When I want to run specific test or suites. I run them from terminal.
I've installed jenkins and configured my first free style project.
I added shell command (ex: `protractor conf.js --suites A --params.user =A`).

Everything works fine. If I want to run multiple suites I must edit my shell command inside jenkins. Is there any workaround?, like checkboxes, so I can check which suites I want to run.

Also I want to know about extensible parameters. I want to select which parameters I want to run. Instead of putting command protractor `conf.js --params.user=oneuser` I want to be able to choose it from GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [parameterized builds](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build).

"First, you need to define parameters for your job by selecting "This build is parameterized", then using the drop-down button to add as many parameters as you need."

"String parameters are exposed as environment variables of the same name. Therefore, a builder, like Ant and Shell, [or protractor] can use the parameters."

So if you make "protractorSuites" a string parameter, you can reference it like:

```
protractor conf.js --suites ${protractorSuites} --params.user =A
```

Then when you "Build with parameters" you can supply the appropriate suite.